# Winforms Applications best way to handle loss of database connection without the application crashing

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I hope this isn t too general a question.

I have quite a few winforms applications which connect to the same sql database.

On one of my servers the CPU is getting to 100% (which is an issue in itself which needs to be investigated).
So i'm getting a - 'The underlying Provider Failed to open'

So my issue is there are a lot of repository requests within the applications and i don t really want to put try catches around all of them - although i have done the following in the main method of one of them:

```
connDb1  == false;
while (connDb1 == false)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       //code in here with various connection to db though repositories...
                        connDb1 = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        connDb1 = false;
                        _keepItDry.AddTolistBox(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": Error connection to DB may have failed - try again... ", _listBoxLog);
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);//wait 1 minute and try again
                    } 
                }
```

Has anyone got a good solution for how to check if the db connection has been lost and retry without the application crashing.

Or is it a case of going through the applications and anywhere which connects error handle there.

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks

Comment: catch the exception(s), then it depends on whats best for the users of your application.

Comment: i do think this may be too general a question i was just trying to think of something which would say right this is a system.data.entity exception so we ve lost connection to the db ... try to connect again in an overall sense.. probably not..

Comment: If we limit the scope to WinForms, I can't know if your users would like to see an infinitely repeating trace of retry attempts or a message box suggesting they contact the system administrator or something else.

Comment: Generally speaking, is a failed connection attempt likely to automatically resolve itself? Once again, this depends on a number of factors.

Comment: @Jodrell the failed connection is likely to resolve when the CPU goes back under 100%

Comment: use .NET 4.5.1, has ADO.NET Connection resiliency built in, but first optimize your queries.

Comment: In your case yes but, how do you distinguish that from a misconfigured connection string or a broken router in your server room. In systems with optimized queries my two suggestions are as likely as your situation but, will not fix themselves. So, there is no generic solution to your problem because your problem is not generic.

Comment: Agreeing with @ErikEJ, use .Net 4.5.1, its better in many ways and obviously, whatever you do, optimize your queries/indecies/schema.

Comment: ok great will definetely look into that